# Clarifying norm convergence proof involving Cesaro summability and Fejer Kernel

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I am working through the Graduate Studies in Mathematics Volume 29 text: Fourier Analysis and am struggling to understand a line in a particular proof.  We are working with $f \in L^p$, $1 \leq p < \infty$ and define
$$ \sigma_N f(x) = \int_0^1 f(t)F_N(x-t)dt, $$
where $F_N$ is the Fejer kernel.  Indeed we have the familiar properties that $F_N(t) \geq 0$ and $\|F_N\|_1 = 1$.  In the proof of Theorem 1.10, which claims that $\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \| \sigma_Nf - f\|_p = 0$, we have the following as the first line:
$$ \| \sigma_Nf - f\|_p = \int_{-1/2}^{1/2}\|f(\cdot -t) - f(\cdot)\|_p F_N(t)dt.$$

In my attempt to understand this I have done the following
\begin{align*}
\sigma_Nf(x) - f(x) ={}& \int_0^1f(x-t)F_N(t)dt - f(x)\\
={}& \int_0^1 f(x-t)F_N(t)dt - \int_0^1f(x)F_N(t)dt\\
={}& \int_0^1 (f(x-t) - f(x))F_N(t)dt.
\end{align*}

So I can write $\|\sigma_Nf - f\|_p = \| \int_{-1/2}^{1/2} (f(x-t) - f(x))F_N(t)dt \|_p.  $  However I fail to see how we can "pass" the norm through the integral and around our Fejer kernel.  I feel strongly it has to do with the integral of the Fejer Kernel being one, but cannot justify it.

Any help clarifying this is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo. Equality does not hold but there is an inequality. See Wikipedia for 'Minkowski's inequality for integrals' to get $\leq $ in place of $=$.

Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality

Comment: Thank you.  I suspected something was up with the equality, but don't quite dare to question GSM textbooks yet!